# Python Playwright start maximized window

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I have a problem starting Playwright in Python maximized. I found some articles for other languages but doesn't work in Python, also nothing is written about maximizing window in Python in the official documentation.

I tried `browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, args=["--start-maximized"])`

And it starts maximized but then automatically restores back to the default small window size.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playwright - Javascript - Maximize Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74341199/playwright-javascript-maximize-browser)

Comment: Thanks, yes this is the fix, it is same as my answer below.

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77281854

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the answer:

I need to set also the following and it works: `browser.new_context(no_viewport=True)`

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `playwright` and `pytest-playwright`.

```py
def test_foo(playwright):
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False, args=["--start-maximized"])
    # create a new incognito browser context.
    context = browser.new_context(no_viewport=True)
    # create a new page in a pristine context.
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("https://example.com")
```

Run tests with `pytest .`, no need to specify the browser and headless params. With `new_context` it won't share cookies/cache with other browser contexts so we get separation of test runs

Answer (score 2):

This is the way you should do it and it works

```
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(args=['--start-maximized'], headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page(no_viewport=True)
    page.goto(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a conftest.py
and define:

```
def page(playwright: Playwright, scope="module"):
    app_data_path = os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA")
    chromium_path = "ms-playwright\\chromium-1028\\chrome-win"
    chromium_path = os.path.join(app_data_path, chromium_path)
    chrome = playwright.chromium\
        .launch_persistent_context(chromium_path, headless=False, args=["--start-maximised"], no_viewport=True)
    page = chrome.new_page()
    return page
```

Then, will be able manually maximize the window and won't restore is back