# How to maximize the Window size in Playwright?

Tags: javascript, viewport, playwright, saucelabs, lambdatest

I'm running my Playwright test scenarios and facing an issue while trying to run scenarios with windows “maximized”  / full window.

I set `viewport` as `null` for browser context, and it works in maximized view on local, but on remote-cloud-providers like LambdaTest/SauceLabs it works only with reduced size.

I tried with view port it does not work: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browser/#browser-new-context-option-viewport.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Specify your language- Python/TS/C#/etc.... It changes from language to another

Comment: nodeJS, I'm using the sample repository provided my these cloud platforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments like below during browser launch:

```
  const browser=  await chromium.launch({ headless: false,
            args:['--window-size=1920,1040']})
  const context= await browser.newContext()
  const page = await context.newPage()
```

Reference:

[Playwright - Javascript - Maximize Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74341199/playwright-javascript-maximize-browser)

Answer (score 1):

### First Way - Via playwright.config file

1. Add `args: ["--start-maximized"]` to the `launchOptions`
2. **Remove** the *DeviceDescriptor* from your project
3. Set `viewport: null` in your project

Example `playwright.config.ts` file:

```
// playwright.config.ts file
import { defineConfig, devices } from "@playwright/test";

export default defineConfig({
  use: {
    launchOptions: {
      // 1
      args: ["--start-maximized"],
    },
  },

  projects: [
    {
      name: "chromium",
      use: {
        // 2 (Make sure device is not set)
        // ...devices["Desktop Chrome"],

        // 3
        viewport: null,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

### Second Way - In the test itself

```js
const browser = await chromium.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--start-maximized"],
});
const context = await browser.newContext({ viewport: null });
const page = await context.newPage();
```

Again, note that you follow these steps:

1. Add `args: ["--start-maximized"]` to the `launchOptions`
2. **Remove** the *DeviceDescriptor* from your project configuration
3. Set `viewport: null` in the `BrowserContext`

Comment: Can you specify with respect to Browserstack?