How to maximize browser window in Playwright
I've 2 questions related to python playscript when launching a browser.
Looks like I can use
def test_has_title(page: Page):
   page.goto("https://my-url.com")

Another way is
with sync_playwright() as p:
  browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, args=["--start-maximized"])
  page = browser.new_page()
  page.goto("https://my-url.com")


What is the correct way of launching the browser? When should I use any of the above?
My browser window is not maximized in spite of --start-maximized argument. What is the way to maximize the browser window?


See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77281854/1831456

You can pass no_viewport to the new_page call. That will do the job.
page = browser.new_page(no_viewport=True)



The second choice is always recommended, as using a context manager will clear out any memory if the browser crashes.
To set the window size of a browser, you need to create a context

    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=True, slow_mo=1000)
        context = browser.new_context(
            viewport={ 'width': 1920, 'height': 968 },
        )
        page = context.new_page()
        page.goto("https://my-url.com")

