# How can I get Playwright to open a browser maximized?

Tags: typescript, playwright

I'm trying to get Playwright to open Chromium maximized.
I've tried (on my test script ):

```
  test('verify an instrument', async ({ page }) => {

    test.setTimeout(60000); // Set the test timeout to 60 seconds

    const login = new LoginPage(page);
    const home = new HomePage(page);
    
**    const browser = await chromium.launch({
      args: ["--start-maximized"],  
      headless: false,
**    });
    
      **const context = await browser.newContext();**

      await context.tracing.start({ screenshots: true, snapshots: true });

      await login.gotoGXFLoginPage();
```

ALSO, I tried on my playwright.config.ts:

```
      /* Configure projects for major browsers */ 
      projects: [
        {
          name: 'chromium',
          use: { ...devices['Desktop Chromium'],
          viewport: null,
   
          launchOptions: {
            args: ["--start-maximized"]
        },
```

But neither approach is working.  Any advice?

I tried the code above, (see problem details), but to no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playwright - Javascript - Maximize Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74341199/playwright-javascript-maximize-browser)