Maximize browser viewport in Playwright
Is there a nicer way to maximize browser in Playwright like it has in other frameworks - browser.maximize() or page.maximize() instead of setting the viewport? Or is there one that is going to come soon with a newer version?
I tried setting the viewport, I felt it would be better to have a method for maximize instead of writing the view port numbers.

Did you try setting const context = await browser.newContext({viewport: null});? This should maximize the viewport. See Playwright - Javascript - Maximize Browser and How to maximize the Window size in Playwright?. When you're referring to "other frameworks", could you specify which you're referring to?

Does this answer your question? How to maximize the Window size in Playwright?

I tried browser.newContext and it did not work with the parameters

When you say it didn't work, what happened exactly? Did you try the other ideas in the existing threads, like args: ["--start-maximized"]?

I tried args: ["--start-maximized"] in my config file. The browser maximizes and flicks from maximized version to minimized version.

Maybe share your complete code and system details. Perhaps you're overriding it with another viewport call?

I was able to do it for tests running in my local. However, it is more complicated when I run the config for a cloud tool (browserstack)

OK, so again, I'd tag accordingly so prospective answerers can find the question, provide a runnable [mcve], package.json and full env details. I don't see any [edit]s by you to the question yet, and almost certainly some will be needed before an answer is likely to happen. Thanks.

use: {
launchOptions: {
args: ["--start-maximized"]
},
},
projects: [
{
name: 'chromium',
use: {
connectOptions: { wsEndpoint: getCdpEndpoint('Desktop Chrome') }
}
},
],
};

Please [edit] the question to provide all of the requested info. (you can click the [edit] link there if you're not sure how to do it). Thanks.

My problem has been resolved. I realized that
const context = await browser.newContext({ viewport: null }) must be specified in the spec file for tests to run with browser size maximized in the cloud tools. However, to run the same on local  launchOptions: {
args: ["--start-maximized"] is enough to launch a browser with maximum size. Thanks for the quick response @ggorlen

No problem, although I'd still provide all the details in your question, then post a self answer. Otherwise all of the information here isn't really in good shape to help future visitors with the same problem as you. Thanks.

See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77552386/19574650, there are three things that you need to notice.
